# Javascript call can not retrieve data from controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller named Map1 which returns a JSON object. I have a .js file named init.js in scripts folder. I'm trying to call that controller in that file like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("/USER_CANCEL/Map1"),
    function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
```

But I see only "null" when in the console. I'm pretty sure that Controller does not return null. I guess my js method that calls the controller doesn't work properly. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: does calling your controller directly from browsers returns anything ?

Comment: @Knitesh Yes, it returns a proper JSON array.

Comment: update your code to use $.getJSON( "/USER_CANCEL/Map1")
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data );
  }) . Let me know if it works

Comment: @Knitesh It returned null again :/

Comment: Can you post the controller code please?

Comment: (: do you see call going to controller and returning data back in your dev tool. (F12 -> Network )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, the below code worked :

```
var myurl = "/USER_CANCEL/Map1";

$.get(myurl, null, function (response) {
});
```